# How do I properly represent this question? (binomial polynomials)

Tags: polynomials, binomial-theorem

The total area of a picture and its frame can be represented by (l + 2f)(w + 2f), where l and w represent the length and width of the picture, respectively, and f represents the thickness of the frame.

a.   Sketch a diagram to represent this scenario.

b. What binomial multiplication represents the area of an 8" x 12" picture and its frame?

This is what i have so far, but I'm not positive it makes sense.

a) [image]
b)(8+2f)(12+2f)

I'm confused on how to represent scenarios like this one that includes multiplying binomials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that frame "thickness" is just adding a border around the picture, then it would be just (8+2f)(12+2f). A good way to think of it is how much you expand the width and length by putting a frame around the picture, that is where the +2f comes from, then it is just the area of a rectangle.